# How to transform values into columns after group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

Input:

```
    column1
A   value1
A   value2
A   value2
B   value3
B   value3
```

Output:

```
    value1   value2   value3
A   1        1        0
B   0        0        1
```

Comment: where is your attempt to do that?

Comment: Like seriously? Three answers to this question... Did you try yourself? The answer is super easy. Easier than all the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

```
for val in df['column1'].unique():
    df[val] = df['column1']==val
df.groupby(df.index).any().drop('column1', axis=1)
```

if you need to convert True/False to 1/0 you can do:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

found an easier method:

```html
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'column1': lambda x: x.tolist()})
cols = sorted(list(set(df['column1'].sum())))
for c in cols:
    df[c] = 1
sessions[cols] = [1 if val in df['column1'] else 0 for val in cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Method #0, just reminded of by another question, you could use `pd.crosstab`:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.index, df.column1).astype(bool).astype(int)
column1  value1  value2  value3
row_0                          
A             1       1       0
B             0       0       1
```

Method #1: you could use `get_dummies` and `groupby` for this:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.column1)
   value1  value2  value3
A       1       0       0
A       0       1       0
A       0       1       0
B       0       0       1
B       0       0       1
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.column1).groupby(level=0).sum()
   value1  value2  value3
A       1       2       0
B       0       0       2
```

gives you the cell counts, and similarly

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.column1).groupby(level=0).max()
   value1  value2  value3
A       1       1       0
B       0       0       1
```

Method #2: add a dummy column and then pivot:

```
>>> d2 = df.reset_index()
>>> d2["dummy"] = 1
>>> d2.pivot_table("dummy", "index", "column1")
column1  value1  value2  value3
index                          
A             1       1     NaN
B           NaN     NaN       1
>>> d2.pivot_table("dummy", "index", "column1", fill_value=0)
column1  value1  value2  value3
index                          
A             1       1       0
B             0       0       1
```